# Android facebook login storing data

Tags: android, database, facebook

I am actually developing an application that allows the user to login though email or Facebook, I did not implemented it yet but I am pretty sure I understood the basic login flow.

On my application there is a part where two user can interact to with each other so someone registered with the classic way need to communicate with someone registered through Facebook, how can do I store or represent the data that concern the inside of my application for the Facebook user ?

Comment: store data in local database or remote database..

Comment: How would I proceed ? I perform the call to the API, get the short lived token, transform it to the long lived token then store all the data. Then do I need to base the uniqueness on the facebook account id ?

Comment: if you want to use facebook as login then use facebook sdk for android       https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0